# How to make EvenHandler work properly in JavaFX?

Tags: java, swing, graph, keylistener, eventhandler

I re-arranged my question so it would be easier.

This code should generate Window and I need console output on press of keyboard.
Window appears but my EventHandlers doesn't works.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Main  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JavaFX in Swing");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Charts charts = new Charts();

        frame.setSize(1024, 720); //Size of dispalayed window
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static class Charts extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

        public Charts(){
            addKeyListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent key) {
            if(key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                System.out.println("DOWN");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent key) {
            if(key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                System.out.println("DOWN");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent key) {
            if(key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                System.out.println("DOWN");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong that this EventHandler is not working?

Comment: work through a tutorial on event handling, apply it to your scenario and when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's not working as expected. Ohh ... and no need for "shouting" words you deem important: we are perfectly capable of grasping what's important :)

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it's better now. I would appreciate any help

Comment: 1. You don't actually register your event handler with anything: i.e. you need to do something like `something.setOnKeyPressed(keyEventHandler);`. 2. Key events are only fired if the node on which they're registered (or a child node) has keyboard focus, which seems unlikely for either the `JFXPanel` or any of the charts. It might be better to register a AWT event handler with your enclosing `JFrame`. You probably need to create a [mre] if you want a full answer.

Comment: please read the referenced help page and __act__ accordingly!

Comment: Yes I did, I totally re-arranged my problem, simplified into all the code above. So I hope it's alright this time. If not I don't know how to do it differently.

Comment: it must be reproducible - as in c&p-a-single-class-into-my-IDE-and-run (you don't expect me to write your boiler-plate code around your problem, do you ;) and don't forget the imports, while usually they are clear, they might be mixed-up in combined swing/fx apps

Comment: You're using swing,if I'm not mistaken. There doesn't seem anything JavaFX related used in the code (or mentioned in the text); Retagged the question.

Comment: I am trying my best here... I have no clue what more to do with this. If this is not right than I guess I am lost. Maybe I don't understand the concept of how is it supposed to be written.

Comment: Also: have a look at the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html , https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // there's no JavaFX in this example
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JavaFX in Swing");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Charts charts = new Charts();

    // add charts panel to frame to allow swing manage it in event processing
    frame.setContentPane(charts);

    frame.setSize(1024, 720); //Size of dispalayed window
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static class Charts extends JPanel {

    public Charts(){
        // Keylistener wont't work if there is no focused component (ie JTextField)
        // JPanel is not focusable component
        // So use registerKeyboardAction to handle events
        registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("DOWN press");
            }
        }, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

        registerKeyboardAction(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("DOWN release");
            }
        }, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    }

}
```